# How to latch a 200mS LOW pulse?

Tags: hardware

Trying to latch a 200 mS, LOW event to log the event.  LOW only occurs when external Watchdog timer sends reset pulse to the Arduino.

Is a D Latch suitable for this application?  It has been years since my digital class; help most appreciated.

How would you proceed?

Comment: Just as a side-note; you know the arduino chips have build in watchdog timers, right?

Comment: I am using Switchdoc Labs, "Dual Watchdog Timer" with an Arduino Mega running a Data logger/web server.

Comment: Project web page: http://tinyurl.com/Data500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question to be :  you want to latch (and indicate) whenever an external watchdog timer has reset your Arduino.

D type flip flop (latch) can be used.  You would use the clock input as the trigger. However, most D types clock on a rising edge. You could use an inverter on the input to the clock to get the D type to clock on a falling edge. You would also connect the D (Data) input high (logic 1). Then when your input (event) goes low, the Q output will latch high.  The 200 mS is irrelevant because the latch ocurrs at the change from high to low (low to high on clock input).

You would also need a means of resetting the latch, which many D types have a reset input or a clear input.

[image]

You could also use a more simple SR latch (set reset latch) using 2 Nand gates.  SR latch changes state when the “set” input goes low (providing that R input was high).  Make the R input go low to reset the latch.

[image]

POSSIBLE ALTERNATIVE :  If you have some means of operator intervention (or even a switch).  You could have your program light an LED at startup.  Operator (person) could reset LED.  Then afterwards,  any reset (restart of program) would light the LED.

Comment: I tried a S-R Latch (74LS279); so far it is not working.  What voltage should I expect on a LOW to the S input?  Measured 150mV, is this a failed 74LS279?

Comment: First, power from 5 volts.     Second : Tie all unused inputs HI. On the SR latch that you are using, R must be high (except when resetting). When S goes low, the Q output should be near 5 volts.

Comment: I have the 74LS279 wired and working; however, there is not enough drive from the external Watchdog timer output.  Will two inverters in series give me more drive?  Measured 2.5 volts at the bottom of the pull-up resistor.   Need to go to the Arduino Mega reset and to the S input of the Latch.  --Thank you for the help!

Comment: Documentation on the [Dual WatchDog](http://www.switchdoc.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/DualWatchDog_101914-V1.3.pdf) is poor. The output is reported as "pulled to ground",  "otherwise high-impedance". You didn't say what value of pull up resistor you are using.  Measuring 2.5 volts indicates that your pull up resistor might be too large of a resistance.

Comment: Normal operation of Arduino (program running) Q= HIGH, S" HIGH, and R= LOW.  When a WATCHDOG reset occurs I see Q go momentarily LOW (0.565 Volts. --HIGH being 4.77 Volts.) Observation made with voltmeter.  Problem is that it happens so fast by the time the Arduino reads the pin for Q status; it is already a HIGH.  I never get a Q value Of LOW when I read the pin connect to Q.  I am trying to do a conditional based on the status of Q. Suggestions?

Comment: You Do NOT want R = Low. . .  Let us try again.  S= Hi . .  R = Hi (presuming that Q=LO after a reset on R). . .  . .When watchdog goes low , (this is tied into the Arduino Reset), and also, S is pulled low by watchdog.  S going low  causes Q to go HI. Q stays HI until R is pulled low by operator (human).

Comment: Now using a D-Latch (74LS74) with an inverter (74LS04) it appears to be working; needs some tweaking and testing.  Weblink has two files of what I am doing with D-Latch code wise and the hook-up to the Arduino Mega-and-SwitchDoc Labs, "Dual Watchdog Timer.".   http://tinyurl.com/74ls74